# Left hand of first tag looks funny after committing an edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Yet more troubles with the left hand edge of the new tags. This only happens to me after committing an edit. Chrome, Windows.

[image: tag with dark black left border]

Comment: I can't reproduce this in Chrome win/os x. Is it still happening to you? Make sure you hard refresh.

Comment: I got instances of this while writing a question on meta using [ tag : id-tech-3 ] and [ tag : id-tech-4 ] | [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pr5PZ.png) - Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The tag design was changed during the Stack Exchange [standardised site design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/179041) rollout, thus this bug is no longer present.

> However, there are several things that will now be standardized to follow the look and feel on Stack Overflow....
>
> - Navigation
> - Fonts
> - Buttons/Icons
> - Tags
> - Newsletter ads